# How to draw a rounded line shape using Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

How can I draw rounded line shape using QT. like this image.I need to design a rounded line when the button click.

```
void MainWindow::on_btnCreateRoundedLine_clicked()
{

}
```

[image]

Updated Image:

[image]

In this code which creates rectangle shape when the button click,likewise I need to create rounded line when the button click.And also which can able to rotate.

```
void Widget::on_btnCreateRect_clicked()
{

    QBrush blueBrush(Qt::green);
    QPen blackPen(Qt::black);
    blackPen.setWidth(2);
    rect = ui->graphicsView->scene()->addRect(-10,-10,250,100,blackPen);

    rect->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable, true);
    rect->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable,true);
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I cannot understand your problem.

Comment: Where do you want to draw it?

Comment: @eyllanesc in the `graphicsView`

Comment: @Learner Please publish the necessary code, that in SO we call it: [mcve]

Comment: @eyllanesc I have't  necessary code to provide sir.I don't have any idea to how I design shape like this.Can you please give me a sample code

Comment: @Learner Those curves have some special equation or can it be any?

Comment: @eyllanesc there no any equation sir,I draw this  using ms paint to show my requirement.I need this type shape.like a half part of oval shape.

Comment: @eyllanesc I posted other image.My plan is design er drawing application,so I need to design curve line for union types.I need to create this **red rounded** type curve.

Comment: @Learner Check my answer, if it works, do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it, check the following link: [tour]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to graph curves, a recommended option is to use [QGraphicsPathItem](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicspathitem.html), to that object you have to pass a [QPainterPath](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainterpath.html):

```
QPainterPath path;
path.moveTo(10, 20);
path.lineTo(10, 40);
path.arcTo(QRectF(10, 20, 40, 40), 180, 180);
path.moveTo(50, 40);
path.lineTo(50, 20);
QPen redPen(Qt::red);
redPen.setWidth(2);
QGraphicsPathItem* item = ui->graphicsView->scene()->addPath(path, redPen);
/*
    QGraphicsPathItem* item = new QGraphicsPathItem(path);
    item->setPen(redPen);
*/
```

Output:

[image]

You can find a complete example in the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/47622771).

Comment: so please tell me how can I change the color of this item when  I select color from color dialog or another way.

Comment: Just change here QPen redPen(Qt::red);